# OpenVPN using Luci (OpenWRT) ssh commands to get instances and enable/disable them

Tags: ssh, grep, openvpn, openwrt

Hey all I have been researching how to go about doing this but I have not really found anything on it.

What I am trying to do is, **use SSH luci**, get a list of all my **OpenVPN instances**:

[image]

**And be able to enable anyone of them by their Name.**

So far the only **ssh command(s)** I have found to list my **OpenVPN instances** are:

```
uci show openvpn
```

Which produces an **output** like this:

```
......[more output here]....
openvpn.sample_client.cert='/etc/openvpn/client.crt'
openvpn.sample_client.key='/etc/openvpn/client.key'
openvpn.sample_client.verb='3'
openvpn.test0=openvpn
openvpn.test0.config='/etc/openvpn/test0.ovpn'
openvpn.test0.enabled='1'
openvpn.test1=openvpn
openvpn.test1.config='/etc/openvpn/test1.ovpn'
```

And

```
tail /etc/config/openvpn
```

Which produces an **output** like this:

```
option key '/etc/openvpn/client.key'
option verb '3'

config openvpn 'test0'
        option config '/etc/openvpn/test0.ovpn'
        option enabled '1'

config openvpn 'test1'
        option config '/etc/openvpn/test1.ovpn'
```

And

```
lsof /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

Which produces an **output** like this:

```
COMMAND     PID   USER    FD   TYPE   DEVICE   SIZE/OFF   NODE     NAME
openvpn   28722   root   txt    REG     0,16     450687   250828   /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

Which would just be nice if I can use **grep** to just get the **names** and **it's PID** from the above **ssh commands** instead of getting all that other data along with it.

**Ideally** I would like the **output** to be like this **(instance name, enabled/disabled and PID)**:

```
test0 enabled  28722
test1 disabled
```

And I know that using:

`/etc/init.d/openvpn stop` or `kill -9 <PID>` to **stop** the **current enabled running instance** and

`/etc/init.d/openvpn start` to **start** the **current enabled running instance**.

Other than that I can not seem to find the proper way of **enabling** and **disabling** an **OpenVPN instance** by it's **name** or **PID**.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Crossposting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76699603/3776858